# How to print float number in SASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am using sasm ide. My question is how to print a float number. This program executes successfully but didn't display any number. My code is given below:

```
%include "io.inc"

section .data
val: dq a123.45

section .bss
res:resq 1
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
   fld qword[val]
 fsqrt
   fst qword[res]


     xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: simliar code: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Floating_Point

Comment: yes, but how to displaay floating point number,it didn't display anthing, please tell me how to display float number

Comment: I don't see any mention of which OS you're targeting.

Comment: please some one tell me how to display floating point number.......

Comment: Use `printf`. I guarantee it's going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%include "io.inc"


section .data
msg: db "Printing float number %f",0 ;format for print string
val: dq 2.45 ;64 bit floating point

section .bss
res: resq 1
section .text

global CMAIN
CMAIN:

    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
 fld qword[val]      ;need to convert 32 bit to 64 bit
   fstp qword[res]   ;floating load makes 80 bit
                     ;store as 64 bit
                     ;push last argument first  
  push dword[val+4] ;64 bit floating point (bottom)
   push dword[val]   ;64 bit floating point (top) 
   push dword[res+4] ;64 bit floating point (bottom)
   push dword[res]   ;64 bit floating point (top)
   push dword msg          ;adress of format string
  call printf
  add esp,20     ;pop stack
  mov eax,0          ; exit code, 0=normal
         xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Answer (score 3):

You can isolate the integer part of the result with `FIST`. Since SASM hasn't got a PRINT_FLOAT-macro you have convert the fractional part of the result into an ASCIIZ-string. This can be manage by isolating the digits by multiplying the fractional part with 10. The resulting integer is the next decimal digit. Pay some attention to the rounding mode, because `FIST` rounds the integer according the current rounding mode! A subsequent `FISUB` must not result in a negative number.

My suggestion:

```
%include "io.inc"

section .data
    val: dq 123.45
    ten: dd 10

section .bss
    leftdigits: resd 1
    rightdigits: resb 100
    temp: resd 1
    control_word: resw 1

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
    fld qword[val]
    fsqrt

    ; modifying rounding mode
    fstcw [control_word]
    mov ax, [control_word]
    or ah, 0b00001100               ; rounding mode: truncating
    mov [temp], ax
    fldcw [temp]                    ; load new rounding mode

    fist dword [leftdigits]         ; store integer part
    fisub dword [leftdigits]        ; clear integer part

    ; load 10 and move it to st(1)
    fild dword [ten]
    fxch

    ; isolate digits of fractional part and store ASCII
    mov edi, rightdigits            ; pointer to ASCIIZ-buffer
    .get_fractional:
    fmul st0, st1                   ; one decimal digit into integer
    fist dword [temp]               ; store digit
    fisub dword [temp]              ; clear integer part
    mov al, byte [temp]             ; load digit
    or al, 0x30                     ; to ASCII
    mov byte [edi], al              ; store to 'rightdigits'
    add edi, 1                      ; increment pointer to string
    fxam                            ; st0 == 0.0?
    fstsw ax
    fwait
    sahf
    jnz .get_fractional             ; no: once more
    mov byte [edi], 0               ; null-termination for ASCIIZ

    ; clean up FPU
    ffree st0                       ; empty st(0)
    ffree st1                       ; empty st(1)
    fldcw [control_word]            ; restore old rounding mode

    PRINT_DEC 4, leftdigits
    PRINT_CHAR '.'                  ; decimal point
    PRINT_STRING rightdigits

    xor eax, eax
    ret
```